# Keep getting "The payload was invalid" exception from ProtectedBrowserStorage

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

In my .NET 5 Blazor Server Application I add dataprotection to my services using the following line in my Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
  .SetApplicationName("WhateverApplicationName")
  .PersistKeysToDbContext<KpaContext>();
```

Now when I try to get data from ProtectedLocalStorage using this code

```
try
{
    var sessionid = await ProtectedLocalStorage.GetAsync<Guid>("BrowserId");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

It keeps throwing this error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was
> invalid.
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Managed.ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 protectedPayload, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[]
> protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus&
> status)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[]
> protectedData)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector
> protector, String protectedData)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorage.GetAsync[TValue](String
> purpose, String key)

The application runs on a docker container.

The table DataProtectionKeys contains a record of a key which is valid from 05-07 till 03-10 so the key should be active.

What am I doing wrong. I used this link to configure data protection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 4):

For me, this was caused by the application trying to load a key\value from ProtectedLocalStorage \ ProtectedSessionStorage that had become corrupt somehow.

The error went away when I used a new key \ value pair so the application effectively just re-stored the data. So for example changing one line of code

from:

```
var storage = await _ProtectedBrowserStore.GetAsync<AppState>("appState");
```

to:

```
var storage = await _ProtectedBrowserStore.GetAsync<AppState>("appStateTest");
```

Cleared the error.

I believe the same result could have been achieved by clearing the browser's localstorage (not just doing a "clear cache \ hard reload"). However I did not test this.

Comment: Yes, clearing the browser's localstorage worked for me. Just wanted to confirm that.